# Elasticsearch results ORDERed BY and GROUPed BY

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I have this mapping model in my elasticsearch index :

```
{
  "my_index": {
    "mappings": {
      "vehicules": {
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "category_id": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "price": {
            "type": "float"
          },
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this index, I've insert some demo data :

```
+--------------+-------------+-------+
|     Name     | Category ID | Price |
+--------------+-------------+-------+
| Car 1        |           1 |  1500 |
| Car 2        |           1 |  4000 |
| Car 3        |           1 |  2500 |
| Motorcycle 1 |           2 |  3000 |
| Motorcycle 2 |           2 |  1400 |
| Motorcycle 3 |           2 |  2700 |
| Truck 1      |           3 | 19000 |
| Truck 2      |           3 | 15000 |
+--------------+-------------+-------+
```

I would like to sort all the product based on price value ASC, and group the results by category. The categories themselves have to be sorted with the price value of her child data. Which give :

```
{
    "2": [      <= Category where the price start with lower price (1400)
        {
            "name": "Motorcycle 2",
            "price": 1400
        },
        {
            "name": "Motorcycle 3",
            "price": 2700
        },
        {
            "name": "Motorcycle 1",
            "price": 3000
        }
    ],
    "1": [
        {
            "name": "Car 1",
            "price": 1500
        },
        {
            "name": "Car 3",
            "price": 2500
        },
        {
            "name": "Car 2",
            "price": 4000
        }
    ],
    "3": [
        {
            "name": "Truck 2",
            "price": 15000
        },
        {
            "name": "Truck 1",
            "price": 19000
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to have that kind of results or something close to it with ES ?  I'm a very beginner with ES and I've tried many different query in the DevTool of Kibana, without success.

---

I think I found the query to have the desired result. I'm not sure it's fully optimized, but it works.

```
GET my_index/my_type/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "grouped_by_cat": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "category_id",
        "order": {
          "min_price_aggs": "asc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "min_price_aggs": {
          "min": {
            "field": "price"
          }
        },
        "list_top_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "name",
                "price"
              ]
            },
            "sort": [
              {
                "price": {
                  "order": "asc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "size": 10000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Does this query seems correct to you?

Comment: Which version of ElasticSearch are you using ?

Comment: I'm using ES v5.2. I will update may answer with a query which return the results I want.

Answer (score 0):

So you can achieve the above result by following query

```
GET my_index/vehicles/_search
{
"size": 0, 
"aggs" : {
    "category_id_aggs": {
        "terms" : {
            "field" : "category_id"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "data": {
                "top_hits": {
                    "size": 10,
                    "sort": [{"price":"asc"}], 
                    "_source": {
                        "includes" : ["name","price"]
                    }
                }
            }  
        }
     }
   }
 }
```